# Add cells then subtract 1 if there is a date in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I am creating a spreadsheet that I track peoples Comp Time. What I am wanting to do is in, say F3 has a beginning balance of 2. Through out the month the gain some additional days (G3=1, H3=2, I3=1, J3=0). in K3 I want to be able to put a date/dates that they used some of the comp time and in L3 to equal the sum of F3 thru J3, then subtract 1 for date that is in K3.

To summarize - F3 (Beginning Balance) has 2, G3=1,H3=2,I3=1,J3=0, K3 (Date(s) Used) has 2 dates of May 5th and May 8th and then L3 (Ending Balance) should then equal 4
F3:J3=6, then subtract 2 because K3 has 2 dates and L3 sum it all up and come up with a total of 4

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a way to identify multiple dates in column K, such as using a comma to delimit your dates.

Here's an example formula for cell L3:

```
    =SUM(F3:J3)-IF(ISBLANK(K3),0,(1+LEN(K3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(K3,",",""))))
```

It's summing F3 through J3, then subtracting the number of commas in cell K3 + 1. If K3 is blank, then subtract 0.

[image]

Comment: So i put in the this formula =SUM(F3:I3)-IF(ISBLANK(K3),0,(1+LEN(K3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(K3,",","")))) and I get this as an answer 1/0. I tried it on different rows, with different dates =SUM(F4:I4)-IF(ISBLANK(K4),0,(1+LEN(K4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(K4,",","")))) with dates being taken 5/23/2022, 5/252022 (K4)and get an answer of 1/3 (L4). For that line the beginning balance was 0 (F4) and then each week (4 weeks) had 1 (G4), 2 (H4) 2 (I4) 0 (J4).

Comment: I edited the formula for F3:J3, to fix the missing cell, but still not getting the correct answer....fully. I see the second number in 1/0 is the correct answer, same with 1/3, 3 is the correct answer. Just not sure how to get rid of the first part of the answer.

Comment: I figured out that the ending balance cells were formatted for days. Changed it to numbers and that fixed everything. Thank You for the help on this

Comment: @Jeff Glad it worked for you. Please consider marking the ACCEPT flag on the answer.